# Using chartjs v2 to show categorical values on axis instead of numeric

Tags: chart.js

In chartjs v2 is there a way to change the numeric values on the axis to categorical text labels instead (low, medium, high) for example ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change just the tick labels use the `callback` property of `ticks`. For example

```
...
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        callback: function(value) {
          if (value === 20)
            return 'Low';
          else if (value === 50)
            return 'Medium';
          else if (value === 80)
            return 'High';
          else
            return '';
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1gfu0tfg/

Comment: This worked well for me except I now just have to figure out how to get it to work with my translations in Angular...